# Non-causal private keys in PICNIC

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, picnic

I've been thinking about [PICNIC](https://microsoft.github.io/Picnic/), the tier 2 NIST post-quantum signature scheme. Leaving aside the innovative multi-party computation zero-knowledge proof structure, the private key is an $n$-bit key for an $n$-bit block cipher and the public key is a single matched plain and cipher pair corresponding to the key. There's no a priori reason why another key could not produce the same pair, merely that it has probability $2^{-n}$. In the case of PICNIC, recovery of a non-causal key is sufficient to produce forgeries under the signature scheme.

We should expect Poisson($1-2^{-n}$) non-causal keys which most of the time means at least two keys to hunt for. The median exhaust time for one key is $2^n/2$, but for one of two keys it is $2^n/\sqrt 2$. Does this count as a legitimate attack given that some of the security requirements for NIST levels are relative to the exhaust cost of AES?

To be clear, I don't think that this is a serious security deficiency. The effect is easy to mitigate by increasing the block size by 1 (there's even some mitigation keeping the key size fixed and only increasing the block size).

Comment: Note that PICNIC is not a NIST scheme (as the link to Microsoft / github readily suggests). It is designed by a team which seems to mainly indicate Microsoft / Greg Zaveruga. It's a round 3 *alternative* candidate for signature algorithms in the PQC standardization effort by NIST.